# Call to undefined function mod_dir()

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to host an app which is already written and i am unable to process beyond this point, I know this might be very little detail to solve this issue. But anyone has any idea what this function is? (mod_dir()). Am i missing a library.

```
<?php
global $dir;
echo 'a';
$dir = mod_dir();
?>
```

Actual error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function mod_dir() in /Users/****/Sites/test/index.php on line 10

Comment: `Call to undefined function mod_dir()`-  that's the exact, literal error message you get?

Comment: Sounds like an Apache module.

Comment: yeah and i just check there is a module name mod_dir in httpd.conf which i have uncommented.

Comment: So this is not the actual error message?

Comment: So... save it and restart apache.

Comment: I didn't know Apache modules could be called as functions anywhere in PHP code, this is odd... Can you provide more details about the exact message and context? The code generating the error and a print of your error screen would help.

Comment: i did restart the server few times

Comment: Oh, so this _is_ supposed to be a actual php function. Guess what: The first hit on google that was not about the apache module of that name was ...this question ;-) Do you have a running/working instance of this script,so that you can investigate what this function actually is and who/what brought it to the table?

Comment: yes i do have a running instance just put the above code in to index.php and host it on a apache server.